# How to bubble sort an array of arrays by the first element in each array?

Tags: python-3.x, bubble-sort

I am trying to sort an array of type array=[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],[x3,y3,z3]] I want to sort the array from smallest x value to largest x value. This is my code but for some reason it is not working I am getting an output of numbers that are not the same numbers that i input not sure why. This should be a simple thing and I have no idea why its not working? here is my code:

```
def bubbleSort(array):
    temp=0
    for wall in range(len(array)):
        for i in range(len(array)-wall-1):
            if(array[i][0]>array[i+1][0]):
                temp=array[i]
                array[i]=array[i+1]
                array[i+1]=temp
    return array
```

sample output:

```
inputarray [[ 41.5838495   73.34464218 119.68507767]
 [ -9.34225497  70.60012142 119.75824833]
 [ 31.54452334  73.8050508  119.64149475]
 [ 35.53872937  74.02030742 119.62592602]
 [ 47.52134148  74.66607698 119.63214874]
 [ 89.46048091  76.92627026 119.57610846]
 [ 44.47187132  75.50318594 119.61503029]
 [ 25.49940313  74.48071753 119.60413456]
 [ 21.50520306  74.26546122 119.67418194]
 [  1.5341789   73.18917842 119.70999241]
 [ -1.46147116  73.02773619 119.67418194]
 [-30.47325963  72.46567821 119.77849007]
 [ 23.44848894  75.37164088 119.63682175]
 [ 27.44269496  75.58689751 119.7286725 ]
 [ 38.42675111  76.17885266 119.68507767]
 [ 58.39777527  77.25513547 119.64460611]
 [ 65.38763134  77.63183432 119.5776701 ]
 [ 69.38183141  77.84709063 119.6010232 ]
 [ 95.29034458  80.24480807 119.44378614]
 [ 76.31787639  79.22233966 119.47492361]
 [ 72.32367334  79.00708319 119.5122838 ]
 [ 64.33526725  78.57657026 119.52785254]
 [ 57.34540522  78.19987109 119.5122838 ]
 [ 49.35699913  77.76935816 119.56521273]
 [ 41.36859304  77.33884523 119.63214874]
 [ 18.40192477  76.10112052 119.54497099]
 [ -4.56474944  74.86339548 119.69131231]
 [-28.52997367  73.57185638 119.57610846]
 [-39.51403577  72.9799009  119.75669861]
 [-48.50099784  72.49557357 119.73800659]
 [-35.57364986  74.19370871 119.64616776]
 [-12.60697564  75.43143374 116.82376862]
 [ -4.6185636   75.86194699 119.49049234]
 [ -0.62436353  76.0772033  119.6772933 ]
 [  3.36983654  76.2924596  119.67418194]
 [ 11.35824859  76.72297285 119.47181225]
 [ 18.34811062  77.09967202 119.70688105]
 [ 22.34231069  77.31492833 119.55275536]
 [ 31.3292668   77.79925533 119.50606108]
 [ 38.31912287  78.17595419 119.55899   ]
 [ 47.30608494  78.66028151 119.50917244]
 [ 54.29594101  79.03698037 119.56832409]
 [ 78.26116525  80.32851948 119.37528849]
 [ 85.25102132  80.70521833 119.42665577]
 [ 89.24522437  80.92047479 119.35504675]
 [ 90.18996031  81.97283889 119.41576004]
 [ 87.19430728  81.8113965  119.32547092]
 [ 83.20010423  81.59614003 119.35038567]
 [ 67.22328907  80.73511402 119.38151121]
 [ 63.22908305  80.51985739 119.47647333]
 [ -6.66947771  76.75286886 119.47959661]
 [-29.63615192  75.51514382 123.19867611]
 [-37.62456397  75.08463057 119.54185963]
 [-45.66679025  75.65267032 119.63214874]
 [-41.67257828  75.86792726 119.53252554]
 [-29.68996616  76.51369682 119.48270798]
 [ -9.7189539   77.58997898 119.47647333]
 [ -5.72474193  77.80523593 119.38618422]
 [  1.2651082   78.18193446 119.46713924]
 [  5.25932017  78.3971914  119.49360371]
 [ 50.19410668  80.81882675 119.38307285]
 [ 61.17816878  81.41078223 119.42199469]
 [ 69.16657487  81.84129516 119.40175295]
 [ 89.13759606  82.91757781 119.24763918]
 [ 93.1317991   83.13283427 119.37372684]
 [ 96.12745213  83.29427666 119.37217712]
 [107.05770015  84.88478216 119.17757988]
 [ 95.07508804  84.2390126  119.28967237]
 [ 72.1084168   83.00128773 119.37217712]
 [ 53.13594861  81.97881932 119.41732168]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-35.78890632  78.18791175 119.63059902]
 [109.94572487  87.04332756 119.05460358]
 [ 94.96745972  86.23611561 119.22895908]
 [-44.82967072  78.70213806 119.46868896]
 [105.89770626  87.82662103 119.27876472]
 [ 93.86128155  88.17940157 119.15267706]
 [-48.93151085  80.48398115 119.39396858]
 [104.73771236  90.7684599  119.22428608]
 [-38.05507706  83.07303964 119.49827671]
 [-50.09150325  83.42582011 119.76759434]
 [-26.12627902  84.71735921 119.3145752 ]
 [101.63443251  92.6041206  119.11219358]
 [-27.17864327  85.66209813 119.26631927]
 [-31.17284334  85.44684183 119.30679083]
 [-39.16125539  85.01632858 119.43756342]
 [-47.14966744  84.58581533 119.33947802]
 [-50.14531749  84.4243731  119.32858229]
 [-49.20058155  85.47673719 119.56832409]
 [-45.20636957  85.69199414 119.34415102]
 [-41.2121695   85.90725044 119.40019131]
 [-34.22231938  86.28394898 119.35038567]
 [-26.23390733  86.71446223 119.30990219]
 [-10.25709514  87.57548808 119.25075054]
 [110.56757678  94.08699775 119.06704903]
 [ 99.52970135  94.49359233 119.04058456]
 [-20.2964094   88.03589734 119.17603016]
 [-47.25729559  86.58291536 119.37685013]
 [ 97.42497151  96.38306711 118.92071962]
 [ 85.4423594   95.73729755 118.88179779]
 [  4.55973654  91.37835354 119.12932396]
 [-26.39534972  89.71011525 119.16824579]
 [ -7.47668965  91.731134   119.14021969]
 [ 12.4943226   92.80741616 119.04214621]
 [ 15.48997266  92.96885839 119.00322437]
 [ 19.48418463  93.18411534 119.04525757]
 [ 23.4783847   93.39937164 119.05926466]
 [ 70.41028315  95.92863579 118.86311769]
 [ 77.40013923  96.30533464 118.9674139 ]
 [ 89.38274837  96.95110403 118.90358925]
 [101.36536197  97.59687367 118.85689497]
 [101.31154789  98.59542369 118.68565083]
 [ 89.32893429  97.94965405 118.68097782]
 [ 85.33473124  97.73439759 118.82419586]
 [ 78.34487517  97.35769873 118.95651817]
 [ 74.35067212  97.14244227 118.87868643]
 [ 70.35646907  96.9271858  118.93472672]
 [ 62.36805703  96.49667255 118.85689497]
 [ 50.38544491  95.850903   118.92071962]
 [ 42.39703882  95.42039007 119.02657747]
 [ 23.42457063  94.39792166 118.87401342]
 [ 11.44195851  93.75215211 118.92850399]
 [  8.44630846  93.59070988 119.00011301]
 [  4.45210839  93.37545357 119.14333105]
 [ -7.53050373  92.72968402 119.0795064 ]
 [-23.50732782  91.86865752 119.15111542]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [ -3.59011789  93.94349332 119.19003725]
 [ 11.38814427  94.7507051  119.06237602]
 [ 19.37655632  95.18121835 118.98298264]
 [ 39.34757453  96.25750083 118.97675991]
 [ 42.34322458  96.41894306 118.94407272]
 [ 58.32004272  97.27996924 118.86000633]
 [ 62.31424279  97.49522555 118.90982389]
 [ 66.30844882  97.71048217 118.72144938]
 [ 89.27512005  98.94820704 118.86467934]
 [101.25773366  99.59397668 118.71989965]
 [105.2519367   99.80923314 118.59223843]
 [ 93.215512   100.16201369 118.72456074]
 [ 77.23869684  99.30098767 118.92071962]
 [ 62.26042872  98.49377556 118.7556982 ]
 [ 58.26622865  98.27851926 118.84132624]
 [ 31.30534841  96.8255376  118.87557507]
 [ -0.64828192  95.10348556 119.1028595 ]
 [  4.290666    96.3711066  119.08106804]
 [ 20.26747819  97.23213246 118.86934042]
 [ 23.26312824  97.39357469 118.80084276]
 [ 27.25733426  97.60883132 118.92071962]
 [ 39.23994638  98.25460087 118.83665323]
 [ 43.23414645  98.46985717 118.76037121]
 [ 47.22835247  98.6851138  118.79150867]
 [ 51.22255849  98.90037042 118.81952286]
 [ 58.21241457  99.27706928 118.76504421]
 [ 62.20661464  99.49232558 118.73857975]
 [ 66.20082066  99.70758221 118.76348257]
 [101.15010551 101.59107671 118.5579896 ]
 [ 81.12527157 101.51334714 118.78372431]
 [ 73.1368625  101.08283405 118.57979298]
 [ 38.18758212  99.19933979 118.79618168]
 [ 31.1977201   98.82264061 118.80084276]
 [ 27.20352002  98.60738431 118.72612238]
 [ 23.209314    98.39212768 118.76659393]
 [  7.23250182  97.53110182 118.97208691]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [ 39.13231806 100.25170388 118.77593994]
 [ 63.0975423  101.54324299 118.66852045]
 [ 82.07000751 102.56571124 118.63894463]
 [ 94.05261963 103.21148079 118.67319345]
 [ 84.01329645 103.67188957 118.69187355]
 [ 42.07415404 101.41169613 118.78372431]
 [ 34.08574795 100.9811832  118.83198023]
 [ 92.9464413  105.15476973 118.63894463]
 [ 73.92015903 105.13085134 118.66697073]
 [ 69.92595598 104.91559487 118.67319345]
 [ 65.93174996 104.70033825 118.66540909]
 [ 30.98246363 102.81684366 118.71989965]
 [ 64.87938587 105.64507419 118.6747551 ]]
sorted array [[-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-55.7061045   76.11307957 119.67418194]
 [-50.14531749  84.4243731  119.32858229]
 [-50.14531749  84.4243731  119.32858229]
 [-50.14531749  84.4243731  119.32858229]
 [-50.14531749  84.4243731  119.32858229]
 [-50.14531749  84.4243731  119.32858229]
 [-50.14531749  84.4243731  119.32858229]
 [-50.14531749  84.4243731  119.32858229]
 [-50.14531749  84.4243731  119.32858229]
 [-50.14531749  84.4243731  119.32858229]
 [-50.14531749  84.4243731  119.32858229]
 [-50.14531749  84.4243731  119.32858229]
 [-50.14531749  84.4243731  119.32858229]
 [-50.14531749  84.4243731  119.32858229]
 [-50.14531749  84.4243731  119.32858229]
 [-50.14531749  84.4243731  119.32858229]
 [-50.14531749  84.4243731  119.32858229]
 [-50.14531749  84.4243731  119.32858229]
 [-49.20058155  85.47673719 119.56832409]
 [-47.25729559  86.58291536 119.37685013]
 [-47.25729559  86.58291536 119.37685013]
 [-47.25729559  86.58291536 119.37685013]
 [-47.25729559  86.58291536 119.37685013]
 [-47.25729559  86.58291536 119.37685013]
 [-47.25729559  86.58291536 119.37685013]
 [-47.25729559  86.58291536 119.37685013]
 [-47.25729559  86.58291536 119.37685013]
 [-47.25729559  86.58291536 119.37685013]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [-26.50297787  91.70721529 119.17914152]
 [ -3.59011789  93.94349332 119.19003725]
 [ -0.64828192  95.10348556 119.1028595 ]
 [ -0.64828192  95.10348556 119.1028595 ]
 [ -0.64828192  95.10348556 119.1028595 ]
 [ -0.64828192  95.10348556 119.1028595 ]
 [ -0.64828192  95.10348556 119.1028595 ]
 [ -0.64828192  95.10348556 119.1028595 ]
 [ -0.64828192  95.10348556 119.1028595 ]
 [ -0.64828192  95.10348556 119.1028595 ]
 [ -0.64828192  95.10348556 119.1028595 ]
 [ -0.64828192  95.10348556 119.1028595 ]
 [ -0.64828192  95.10348556 119.1028595 ]
 [ -0.64828192  95.10348556 119.1028595 ]
 [ -0.64828192  95.10348556 119.1028595 ]
 [ -0.64828192  95.10348556 119.1028595 ]
 [ -0.64828192  95.10348556 119.1028595 ]
 [ -0.64828192  95.10348556 119.1028595 ]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [  3.23828984  97.31584488 119.05460358]
 [ 30.98246363 102.81684366 118.71989965]
 [ 30.98246363 102.81684366 118.71989965]
 [ 30.98246363 102.81684366 118.71989965]
 [ 30.98246363 102.81684366 118.71989965]
 [ 30.98246363 102.81684366 118.71989965]
 [ 30.98246363 102.81684366 118.71989965]
 [ 30.98246363 102.81684366 118.71989965]
 [ 30.98246363 102.81684366 118.71989965]
 [ 30.98246363 102.81684366 118.71989965]
 [ 30.98246363 102.81684366 118.71989965]
 [ 30.98246363 102.81684366 118.71989965]
 [ 30.98246363 102.81684366 118.71989965]
 [ 64.87938587 105.64507419 118.6747551 ]]
```

Comment: Works for me! It gives me `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [3, 2, 1]]` for input `[[1,2,3],[3,2,1], [2,1,3]]`

Comment: As a side note: `sorted(array, key=lambda x:x[0])` should work. Except if it is an exercise you should avoid reimplementing your sorting algorithm :)